# Asp.Net Core Version Conflict

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I really don't understand what is happenedd.

I try to reinstall Peged.Mvc 4.5 because he could not restoring but the package install failed.

This is my project([link](https://pastebin.com/h848XQEE)):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-CakeStore.App-AC71878A-B74D-42FA-9DBD-6A49AEF1E9A1</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MimeMapping" Version="1.0.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="PagedList.Mvc" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Users\Controllers\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\Users\Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\Users\Models\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\Users\Views\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\products\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\User\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CakeStore.Data.Admin\CakeStore.Data.Admin.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CakeStore.Data.Logging\CakeStore.Data.Logging.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CakeStore.Data.Products\CakeStore.Data.Products.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CakeStore.Data\CakeStore.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_CookieConsentPartial.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_StatusMessage.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Areas\Admin\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Areas\Admin\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1107  Version conflict detected for
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions. Install/reference
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.2.0 directly to
>   project CakeStore.App to resolve this issue.   CakeStore.App ->
>   CakeStore.Data -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.2.0 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.0 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.2.0 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)
>   CakeStore.App -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && <
>   2.2.0).   CakeStore.App   D:\C#\GITHUB\Cake-Store-App\CakeStore.App   D:\C#\GITHUB\Cake-Store-App\CakeStore.App\CakeStore.App.csproj  1

I tried to install directly to project but recived the same errors. I read many issues but steel cant understand.

Answer (score 0):

You mix different versions of net core. Try to update all projects to net core 2.2.

Cakestore.data is using 2.2.0
cakestore.app  is using 2.1.1